# Magento 2 - How to change fonts

Tags: magento2, frontend, fonts, styles

How do I change the font family (at a theme level) to Helvetica in Magento 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) To add a [Google Font](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html):

Go to `<theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` and add it like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <!-- Add local resources -->
    <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>

    <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
    <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
    <link src="js/sample.js"/>

    <!-- Add external resources -->
<css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" /> 
</head>
```

[Reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css)

2) To add a font file:

1- `app\design\frontend\Vendor\CustomTheme\Magento_Theme\layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/custome.css" /> 
    </head>
</page>
```

2- Put your fonts in the below custom theme directory. `app\design\frontend\Vendor\CustomTheme\web\fonts`

3- Now include your custom fonts in `app\design\frontend\Vendor\CustomTheme\web\css/custom.css`

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        src: url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.svg#Open Sans') format('svg');
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal
    }
      [1]: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Quick_Start
      [2]: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css
```

[Reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html)

Finally change the body, div, p etc.. in a css file with `font-family` property

**nb:**  Some themes have the possibility to change this via the settings design theme in Admin panel.

Comment: You can use  font-path to the ttf or wof files: @font-path:'@{baseDir}fonts/<path_to_font_file>' .

 @{baseDir} stands for the app/design/frontend/<you_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial how to add fonts to less.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'd be best off changing the font variable in a _theme.less file. In app/design/frontend/YourCompany/yourtheme/web/css/source/_theme.less, add this to the file:

@font-family-body: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

(or whatever)

This would change the default body font site-wide. You might need to do the same for @font-family__serif and @font-family__sans-serif.

Note: it's totally fine if _theme.less is just a few lines, since it's just variable overrides. To see the variables you're overriding / the ones available to override, check out lib/web/css/source/lib/variables